# I have a BM 800 Mic that isnt working?

Tags: microphone, audio

I have recently got a bm 800 mic that i have plugged into my Yamaha audiogram 6 interface with phantom power and the microphone is just not working. Plugged it directly into my pc and i get audio but it is very quiet because of the little power. Anyone know why the mic isn't working with the audio interface?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Buzzing, Hissing input level issues BM-700 BM-800 NW-800 Neewer/Floureon](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/44184/buzzing-hissing-input-level-issues-bm-700-bm-800-nw-800-neewer-floureon)

Answer (score 2):

Troubleshoot this through elimination.

1. Test the interface with a different condensor mic and cable to identify whether the interface itself or the cable is faulty.
2. Test the BM800 with another interface to identify if the mic is faulty.

It appears as though the BM800 requires phantom power. Ensure that Phantom power (+48v) is configured and working correctly by using the above troubleshooting steps.

Answer (score 2):

According to this review - SoundReview.org : BM-800 [Professional Studio Condenser Microphone Review -](https://soundreview.org/studio/bm-800-professional-studio-condenser-microphone-review/) the BM800 is supplied in two configurations, battery & phantom powered.

First test would be to identify which you have.

> The BM-800 is sold under several brand names. Depending on the brand
> you choose, you can get a battery powered model or a phantom powered
> model. To avoid potential confusion, be sure to pay close attention to
> the specifications while shopping.
>
> Naturally, a mic powered by 48v
> is going to be more powerful than one powered by a 9v battery, many AA
> batteries, or a  5v USB charger.
>
> With your BM-800 you’ll also receive
> a female XLR to 3.5mm stereo cable. To ensure optimum performance, be
> sure that your mixer, audio interface, or computer are able to provide
> enough power for the microphone via the 3.5mm connection. When using
> laptops and desktops, some users have reported low volume recordings.
> However, I’ve also seen users sufficiently power the microphone with
> the provided cable using phantom power as low as 14v.

I'd also wonder what interfaces could provide phantom power over a mini-jack ...
I've never seen one, but then again, I've never looked for one.

Answer (score 1):

When recording voiceovers digitally i always run the condenser into a mixer first and insert a compressor over the channel then take an auxillary out to the pc to control the volume.

THis way you will have a preamp to gain the volume up with to get a decent signal into the desk and to some monitors or headphones

Plugging a condenser straight in it would either have to  have a battery for power or have phantom supplied to it by the interface. eitherway i never put mics straight in without going through a desk wich will generally have a reasonable preamp so your signal should sound better.

Answer (score 1):

You will need an XLR connector to plug into the Yamaha interface for the phantom power to reach the mike. A TRS connector or adaptor to 3.5mm will not do it.